# A question on making fractals with python using turtle and recursion

Tags: recursion, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *

def snowflake_side(length,levels):
    if levels == 0:
        forward(length)
        return

    length /= 3.0
    snowflake_side(length, levels -1)
    left(60)
    snowflake_side(length, levels -1)
    right(120)
    snowflake_side(length, levels -1)
    left(60)
    snowflake_side(length, levels -1)


def create_snowflake():
    pass

# create_snowflake()
snowflake_side(200,2)
mainloop()
```

this is my code so in this as you can see 2 variables levels and length are passed to the function
levels is 2 before the first recursive call and 1 before the second recursive call.I didn't reassign it so how can it be 1

Answer (score 0):

You call it with levels = 2

```
snowflake_side( 200, 2 )
```

And during that function, it **calls itself** with the current levels (2) `-1`

```
snowflake_side( length,  levels -1 )
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion